# UrhoSharp - how to draw lines given points?

Tags: graphics, drawing, cross-platform, urhosharp

I'm trying to figure out how to draw shapes in UrhoSharp and I'm not getting anywhere with it.  I thought it would be pretty straightforward.  Searching the internet is not giving me much to go on.

All I want to do is give points so that I can draw lines between the points.  2-dimensional lines.  So I can then draw shapes like a rectangle or triangle.  I've looked at SkiaSharp, and drawing shapes is pretty straightforward, but for some reason, this concept seems foreign to UrhoSharp, at least from what I've looked at.

I've found a couple of code fragments where people are asking questions but I have no idea what else is going on aside from the bits that they show.  If someone can point me to a reference that clearly explains how to do this, or show me here, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your example:

```
CustomGeometry geom = node.CreateComponent<CustomGeometry>();
geom.BeginGeometry(0, PrimitiveType.LineList);
var material = new Material();
material.SetTechnique(0, CoreAssets.Techniques.NoTextureUnlitVCol, 1, 1);
geom.SetMaterial(material);

float size = 1;

//x
geom.DefineVertex(Vector3.Zero);
geom.DefineColor(Color.Red);
geom.DefineVertex(Vector3.UnitX * size);
geom.DefineColor(Color.Red);
//y
geom.DefineVertex(Vector3.Zero);
geom.DefineColor(Color.Green);
geom.DefineVertex(Vector3.UnitY * size);
geom.DefineColor(Color.Green);
//z
geom.DefineVertex(Vector3.Zero);
geom.DefineColor(Color.Blue);
geom.DefineVertex(Vector3.UnitZ * size);
geom.DefineColor(Color.Blue);

geom.Commit();
```

Refer [here](http://urho3d.prophpbb.com/search.php?keywords=CustomGeometry) for any future examples.

Comment: I've looked around, and I will keep looking, but I'm not seeing anywhere, how to actually put this CustomGeometry on the screen.  What do I need to add to get it to show up?